# Combination of rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am searching for a function or some idea of how I can generate all possible combinations of certain set of elements.

Let's consider that the elements are stored in a column `element` in a table and they are letters. Here it is an example:

```
id | element
1  | a
2  | g
3  | d
...| ...
```

As result I need to have the following output:

```
output
a
g
d
aa
ag
ad
ga
gg
gd
da
dg
dd
aaa
aag
aad
...
```

Is it feasible using MySQL only and no programming language?

Comment: have a look at one of my previous questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031288/php-brute-force-password-generator

Comment: Based on the repeating `a` values in your sample results, it seems like you'd end up generating an infinitely long list.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli OP has to specify a max number of chars for result or else you will most certainly be right

Comment: Actually (not 100% sure) I believe it's `(n+1)!` where `n` is the number of entries in his list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing the max number of characters you wanted, e.g., 3, you could do it like this:

```
select distinct concat(t1.element, t2.element, t3.element) as Combination
from (
    select element from `Test` union all select ''
) t1
cross join (
    select element from `Test` union all select ''
) t2
cross join (
    select element from `Test` union all select ''
) t3
order by length(Combination), Combination
```

But, because this method relies on creating another `JOIN` (and modifying the `CONCAT` statement) for each character you add in length, it cannot be entirely dynamic.

Comment: Note: I added `DISTINCT` to eliminate duplicates, and modified the `ORDER BY` clause to match your desired output.