# Is there a library that would produce a string that would hash (SHA1) to a given input?

Tags: c++, encryption, hash, sha1, sha

I'm wondering if it's possible to find a block of text that would hash to a known value. In particular, I'm looking for a function CreateDataFromHash() that could be called as follows:

```
unsigned char myHash[] = "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709";
unsigned int length = 10000;
CreateDataFromHash(myHash, length);
```

Here `CreateDataFromHash` would return the string of the length 10000 containing arbitrary data, which would hash to `myHash` using SHA1.

Thanks.

Comment: If there was a way to do this in any reasonable amount of time, encryption would not work.

Comment: Nice try, NSA. You'll just have to do your own research.

Comment: You have to brute force it. See

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031288/php-brute-force-password-generator

Comment: why do you need to do this ... maybe if we knew what you're trying to achieve, we can suggest alternative ways because as you can read below - you'll have a very hard time (a very long long log time at that) to do this

Comment: Actually, there are vulnerabilities in MD5 and SHA1, but I think they all rely on having an original text that hashes to that value, and they still take ungodly amounts of processor time.

Comment: @mkb: actually, there's a collision attack against MD5 that can run in an hour or so even on an older machine (e.g., a Pentium IV).

Comment: other than fun and research, can any one come up with a non-nefarious reason to want to find a hash collision? Even if your answer is "I want to test the strength of my existing hash", my response would be "if you're concerned about your hash's security, then use a stronger hash"

Comment: That particular hash is the sha1 of the empty string.

Comment: Note that although the SHA-1 function has been weakened, not a single SHA-1 collision is known (as of 2012-03-25). Calculation of SHA-1 collisions is currently academic, and if IAIK Gratz is any example, the academics fail as well. It has been weakened enough to switch to SHA-2 or 3 for signatures though.

Comment: mkb, I actually know the original hash and the original data so do you know any links to read it up?

Answer (score 5):

There's no known easy or even moderately difficult way to do this in general.

The entire point of hashes (or so-called [one-way functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function)), is that it's easy to compute them, but next to impossible to reverse their computation (find input values based on output). That said, for some hash functions, there are known methods that may allow computing inputs for a given hash value in reasonable time.

For example, this [MD5 sum technique](http://cryptography.hyperlink.cz/md5/MD5_collisions.pdf) will find collisions (but not input for a given output) in about 8 hours on a 1.6GHz computer.

For SHA-1 in particular you may be interested in [reading this](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html).

Answer (score 2):

One of the purposes of SHA1 is that this should be very hard to do.

Comment: Are there *any* other purposes of a hashing algorithm?

Comment: Well storing passwords isn't the only use of hashes.

Comment: Yes, but all the uses of hashes depend on not being able to force collisions

Comment: How hard it is to force a collision will depend on the hashing algorithm and the length of the hash.

Comment: @jalf No. One other purpose is to spread input data evenly across a range. In hash tables, the ability to force a collision is usually irrelevant (unless you want to guard against DOS attacks via malicious user input on a web server … this *is* a real problem!).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: but again, if again, in a hash table your performance depends on the data being spread evenly. Which it might not be if the hashing algorithm is flawed in this manner. :) Your assumptions that hashes will be evenly spread is shot as soon as there is a way to generate collisions reliably

Comment: @jalf Not really. For instance if I know my input domain I could use a perfect hash generator for those inputs to generate perfect spread. In that case I don’t care if all other potential inputs generate collisions. In general, perfect spread doesn’t preclude (even intentional) collisions. It only does if we explicitly need to prevent malicious or averse use cases (prime example of this: quicksort implementations which regress on almost-sorted data … iTunes had this problem once).

Answer (score 1):

hashing is a one way function. you can't get input from the output.

Comment: This isn't about getting the original input back.

Comment: Sure you can get the input from the output, ever heard of Rainbow tables ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table

Comment: Walter, do you have any paper on how this could be used for SHA1?

Comment: There isn't much to it. 1. Get a rainbow list for SHA1 hashes (this file will be tens of gigabytes in size), 2. get a program that will run your hash against the list. 3. Wait for hours while the program works. I haven't done this in years, so the wait time may be less on modern processors.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a "preimage attack". No such thing is publicly known against SHA-1.

The only attack known against SHA-1 is a collision attack. That means I find two inputs that produce the same result, but neither of them is pre-ordained, so to speak. Even so, this attack isn't really feasible for most people -- based on the amount of computation involved, the closest I can figure is that you'd have to spend somewhere in the range of a few million dollars to build a machine that would give you about one colliding pair of keys per week (assuming it ran, doing nothing else 24/7).

Comment: I just need to add, this is not about getting the correct string of data. But maby it doesn't matter when it comes to time?

Comment: @user1188404: Yes -- getting the original string back isn't even theoretically possible except by accident. This is just about finding *a* pair of inputs that produce the same result (in fact, the colliding pairs that are found are normally only a few bytes long).

Answer (score 0):

You have to brute force it. See

[PHP brute force password generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031288/php-brute-force-password-generator)

Get string, do hash, compare, repeat

Comment: Or google the hash string and see if someone has already done it :P